# Dropdown combo box doesn't align

Tags: html, forms, css

See: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/RaORwd

I'm on Mac / Chrome. The 2 text fields align properly but not the dropdown box. Anyone knows what causes this?

```css
* {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
form {
  margin-top: 1%;
}
input {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 2rem;
  border: 1px solid lighten(grey, 30%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
select {
  width: 18rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
}
input,
select {
  margin-left: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  First Name:
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <br>
  <br>Country:
  <select>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not aligning properly because the label "Country:" is shorter than the other two. To fix this, you should use `position` attribute instead of `margin-left`. This will make sure that you are aligning your components relatively to the page and not to the labels.

Here's a quick example with `position:absolute`:

```
*
{
font-family:"Open Sans";
}

form
{
margin-top:1%;
}

input
{
width:18rem;
height:2rem;
border:1px solid lighten(grey,30%);
border-radius:4px;
position: absolute;
left: 20%;
}

select
{
width:18rem;
height:2.2rem;
position: absolute;
left:20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can't use margin-left: 6rem; to align them like you want. You can use 2 way to do:

1 - use table with 2 columns (very easy): 
     + put label "First Name: ","Last Name: ",.. in first column
     + put input and select in seconds column

2 - use div to contain label and another contain input or select, and now you can use css to align div like you want

3 - you can use bootstrap form and example if you don't good at css =)